# Is there a way to redirect a mobile response webpage to desktop version?

Tags: android, web

How can I redirect a mobile response webpage with URL m.facebook.com which has parameters included, to a desktop version?

When I tried with User-agent in `httpResponse` it redirected to the same URL with *m* as subdomain but in the desktop version.

How to resolve this, or is there an alternative way?

Comment: From where? Do you control the server? If not, at best you can try and guess at what the "desktop" version is. `mobile` or `m` as a subdomain is a good heuristic but that's it. There is no standard API that I am familiar with that will let you do so. The best you could do is spoof your User-Agent as you mentioned but sites are under no way required to comply with sending you a "desktop" version

Answer (score 0):

There is no "simple way" to do this since there is no standard API that I am familar with to do this. For your example on the Chrome Mobile Browser, you still load "m.facebook.com"

If you really do want to do this, though you can do a few heuristics:

1. Try to swap the user agent change and see if you get a response that is "different enough"
2. You try removing common prefixes such as "m" or "mobile"
3. You can ship mappings of common sites, i.e: m.facebook.com > facebook.com with your binary
4. You can screenshot the page, run metrics against it, figure out if it's "mobile" or "desktop" and try to redirect.

But there is no way to ask directly.